# Python iterate list and add result to end of url

Tags: python

I have a list - [1,2,3,4]
and a url     - https://www.somewebsite.com

I want to create a for loop to iterate over the list elements and add is to the end of the url.

example...https://www.somewebsite.com/1, https://www.somewebsite.com/2 etc

Thanks for your help,

Comment: "I want to create a for loop to iterate over the list elements and add is to the end of the url." Well do it then...

Comment: `urls = ['https://www.somewebsite.com/'+str(n) for n in [1,2,3,4]]`

Comment: `result = ["https://somewebsite.com/{}".format(i) for i in [1,2,3,4]]`

Comment: @Sudheesh Singanamalla Do we need `.format(str(i))`?. `.format(i)` enough?

Comment: Yup, that's fine! Made the corrections

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum, tutorial or code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem. [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a_url = 'https://www.somewebsite.com'
urls = []

for n in a_list:
    url = '{}/{}'.format(a_url, n)
    urls.append(url)


>>> urls
['https://www.somewebsite.com/1', 'https://www.somewebsite.com/2', 'https://www.somewebsite.com/3', 'https://www.somewebsite.com/4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line using list comprehension:

```
list_1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
url='https://www.somewebsite.com'

print(["{}/{}".format(url,i) for i in list_1])
```

output:

```
['https://www.somewebsite.com/1', 'https://www.somewebsite.com/2', 'https://www.somewebsite.com/3', 'https://www.somewebsite.com/4']
```